# how can i stop the grandmapocolypse without the elder pledge or covanant

Tags: cookie-clicker

I've played cookie clicker and I can only temporarily stop the grandmapocolypse with elder pledge and elder covenant is too expensive

Comment: Also, the grandmapocolypse(its written like this in the game) isnt too bad, if you wanna know why check out the wiki :)

Comment: Have you ascended yet? With the Persistent Memory perk speeding up your research to 2 mins per item, the grandmapocalypse isn't too big of a deal :). With the boosts to your grandmas too they actually become something worth investing time into. I'd recommend doing things that way, getting Persistent Memory and then just breezing through the Grandmapocalypse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one other way to stop the grandmapocolypse: selling all your Grandmas. This lasts until you rebuy one.

Another way out would be ascending and not buying the "One mind" upgrade in the next game.

Comment: thx ill try that

Comment: I did not know that. I guess it should have been more obvious though haha.